# Generating .MD files from XML Documentation for C++?

Tags: documentation

I am searching for a way to generate Markdown files from XML Documentation files (like the ones generated by Visual Studio). I have found several tools (Vsxmd, DefaultDocumentation, etc.) that do this for .NET/C# projects, but I couldn't find anything similar for C++.

Of course, I know there is Doxygen, but in my oppinion its output looks kind of "stale", which is why I want to generate Markdown files and publish them later using a static site generator.

I have spent hours on googling, but cannot find a smart way to do this. I don't want to just parse the XML file, but also generate code references for the undocumented items. Is that possible?

Comment: you could spend a few hours (er days) learning xml stylesheets!

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I don't want to just parse the XML file, but also generate code references for the items that are not mentioned in the XML documentation file because they are not documented. Of course I know how to parse XML.

Comment: you're a member of a dying breed then, I'd take advantage of your knowledge!  I've ran into the same problems with SuSE linux and their "Wicked" network manager.  It's about half documented, all the good parts are in the XML spec.